# How do I go to an email when the item found is an attached file and not a message?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

When I find an attached file when doing a search in Outlook, how do I get to the email containing the file? See the attached screenshot for the search result which prompted this question.

I guess I might be able to do another search based on metadata from the first search, but is there any way to get straight to the email in question?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you select the displayed attachment?

Comment: @harrymc It opens the attachment

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, i notice that you just type the key word in search bar but not confirm to search, and the results are suggested results. Please press Enter to open the message that contains this attachment in the search results.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.